# Create a grouped plot by more than one factor

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, ggplot2, dplyr

I'm currently investigating the advantages of `dplyr` and `ggplot`. In one of my plots I have a `data.frame` containing two factors, namely `F1` and `F2`. I wanted to create a line plot for each possible combinations of `F1` and `F2` (Cartesian product, here `4=2 x 2` outcomes).

It seems, that `ggplot` only accepts one factor here `F1`. So that the lines in my plots are connected, whereas I expect four separate lines.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df<-data.frame("X"=c(1,2,4,5,7,8,10,11),"Y"=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),"F1"=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),"F2"=c(1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2))
df$F1<-as.factor(df$F1)
df$F2<-as.factor(df$F2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=X, y=Y, group=F1, color=F2))+geom_line()
```

A workaround might be to add a new column to my dataframe combining `F1` and `F2`, but I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: I recommend to use `facets`, like `facet_grid`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that you can only specify one factor to control the grouping. If you want to use more than one, you can use the [`interaction`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3/topics/interaction) function to work out the combination:

```
# you can either calculate the interaction beforehand and supply that...
df$F1F2 <- interaction(df$F1, df$F2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = X, y = Y, group = F1F2, color = F1F2)) + geom_line()

# or you can just drop it straight in!
ggplot(df,
  aes(x = X, y = Y, group = interaction(F1, F2), color = interaction(F1, F2))) +
  geom_line()
```

You can also use the arguments to `interaction` to control how it's formatted (for plot presentation).

Alternatively, you can find other ways to visualise multiple factors. For example, you might use one factor for grouping, and then use [facetting](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/#section-facetting) to display levels of another factor (or two more, in fact).

Comment: Thanks. Interaction was actually the thing I was looking for.